# How to pass SNS TopicARN through boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have two regions us-east-1 and us-east-2
I want to pass the SNS topic ARN

```
response = client.get_topic_attributes(
    TopicArn='string'
)
```

region = us-east-1
number =123

region = us-east-2
number=456

where my string will contain

> 'arn:aws:sns:{region}:{number}:{topic-name}'

how can I pass the string?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: in TopicARn I want to pass region variable and number variable how can pass those 2 variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python):

```
response = client.get_topic_attributes(
    TopicArn=f'arn:aws:sns:{region}:{number}:{topic-name}'
)
```